# Multiple Divs that Stretch to size of window

Tags: css, html

I was able to make one `div` go to the stretch of the window size AKA fill the screen. Now I'm wondering how the rest don't overlap each other so I can scroll through each of them in order, retaining the centered text in each div as well? Right now, it's only displaying thing 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/592NY/1/

What I am trying to achieve:
[image: demo]

Here is the annotated CSS:

```css
/* Each of the divs and their independent backgrounds */
  #thing1 { 
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:1000;           
            background: blue;
}
#thing2 {   
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:1000;           
            background: red;
}
#thing3 {   
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:1000;           
            background: green;
}
/* Centering the text */
#text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have some logic I don't understand or you wish to go full 3D :D
The three divs have same z-index, none of them has it's opacity modified soo they'll simply appear in the order they appear in the HTML (if you move thing 3 before thing 2, thing 2 will be visible). Thing 2 is currently "on top" of thing 1 and thing 3 is on top of thing 2.

As I said 3D , you can use firefox's 3D view to see what's happening.

Update: you can use `top: 100%` for the second div and `top: 200%` for the third, which surprisingly seems to work even on IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/592NY/4/

Comment: How can I make them not overlap then? :D

Comment: How exactly do you want the whole thing to look like ?

Comment: Check my question, I added an image.

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute positioning and all three have the same z-index, so the last one will appear on top of the other two. If you reduce the z-index of the third item, then the second div will now be on top.

Ids must be unique on the page, so "text" should be a class.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgsw/592NY/5/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#thing1 {   
            position: relative; 
            height: 100%;           
            background: blue;
}
#thing2 {   
            position: relative; 
            height: 100%;   
            background: red;
}
#thing3 {
            position: relative; 
            height: 100%;       
            background: green;
}
.text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It is not necessary to specify `width: 100%` for DIVs, this is their default behaviour.

It is much neater to give these *similar* boxes a **class**, then colour them using their ids:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgsw/sMSPa/2/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.things {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#thing1 {               
    background: blue;
}
#thing2 {
    background: red;
}
#thing3 {   
    background: green;
}
.text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to achieve. As your code stands, there will only ever be one visible, on top of the other two.

Comment: I am trying to achieve `how the rest don't overlap each other so I can scroll through each of them in order` . Can you explain in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/592NY/2/

Remove the absolute and z index since overlapping is not desired.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#thing1 {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: blue;
}
#thing2 {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: red;
}
#thing3 {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: green;
}
#text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Now, each div seems to be a little taller than the window?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/592NY/3/ Sorry see now..I think this is what you are looking for.