# How to position multiple screen filled (responsive) DIV's?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm working on this for a couple of days but can't figure out how to do this properly. I want to have a website that contains 25 images. Now, every image should be screen filling, and therefore be responsive, so that on every screen, small or big, the height of one image (for example) is always 100%. Now I want the 25 images to be positioned in a grid of 5x5.

Question: how can I position this properly? I tried putting the images in DIVs and giving their ID's positions in % up to 400%.

This image below explains the principle of the grid, and what should happen when you resize your browser window (situation 2).

[image: How I want the site to work]

Any ideas how I can solve this (with CSS probably)?
Here are some other threads that I looked at:
[Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css)
and
[Multiple Divs that Stretch to size of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284899/multiple-divs-that-stretch-to-size-of-window)

I'm making a portfolio website for an artist and the idea is that you can scroll and navigate (via a dropdownlist and a scrollto jQuery) through screen filling images only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First : positioning the divs**

Set

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

So you have a baseline that follows the width/height of the viewport.
Then, make a container that will contain all the "pages" with `width:500%; height:500%;`

Use child `div`s to create each "page" and give them `width:20%; height:20%;` (these divs will then be 100% width/height of viewport). And float them left so they align like a grid.

**Second : the images**

The best aproach here would be to set the images as background images of each child `div` (="pages") and use the CSS property `background-size:contain;` and `background-position:center center;` so they adpat/crop and center horizontaly/verticaly according to viewport height/width.

Using this technique will save you from blanks between images and images loosing theire aspect ratio.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s97Ug/13/)

---

**Alternative solution with `<img>` tag**

I don't recomend this solution exept if you don't mind having gaps on the right/left of images on screens that have a wider aspect ratio than your images.

Images are resized using `width:auto; height:100%;` to adapt like in your example. They are horizontaly centered with `display:block; margin:0 auto;`

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s97Ug/8/)

---

**Code for the background technique :**

HTML :

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="image img1"></div>
    <div class="image img2"></div>
    <div class="image img3"></div>
    <div class="image img4"></div>
    <div class="image img5"></div>
    
    <div class="image img4"></div>
    <div class="image img5"></div>
    <div class="image img1"></div>
    <div class="image img2"></div>
    <div class="image img3"></div>
    
    <div class="image img1"></div>
    <div class="image img2"></div>
    <div class="image img3"></div>
    <div class="image img4"></div>
    <div class="image img5"></div>
    
    <div class="image img4"></div>
    <div class="image img5"></div>
    <div class="image img1"></div>
    <div class="image img2"></div>
    <div class="image img3"></div>
 
    <div class="image img1"></div>
    <div class="image img2"></div>
    <div class="image img3"></div>
    <div class="image img4"></div>
    <div class="image img5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap {
    width:500%;
    height:500%;
}
.image {
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
    float:left;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.img1{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-1724-977-9.jpg);
}
.img2{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1724-977-1.jpg);
}
.img3{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-1724-977-5.jpg);
}
.img4{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1724-977-8.jpg);
}
.img5{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-g-1724-977-9.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot web-tiki, it makes sense how you explain it but wouldn't ever find it myself. You're the best! :)

Comment: Will share the resulting website by tomorrow!

Comment: For the navigation I make use of a jQuery that scrolls to the positions of the ID's of the 25 specific DIV's. Now that the DIV's have classes, the jQuery can't 'find' their positions anymore. Do you maybe know how I can give them back their ID's?

Comment: @Kaleid0sk0p you can just give every div a unique id, is there an issue with that?

Comment: Sorry I was too quick with commenting, it does work fine now! ;)

Comment: Hi web-tiki here's the final website, an artist's portfolio page: http://fionalutjenhuis.com/. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your options. But you can make 25 div/section elements, which get height and width from screen jQuery could do this if this is ok for you?

On those elements you need to make

```
div,section{
 background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg); 
 background-size:cover; 
 background-position:left top;
}
```